# Unable to list all members of a Enterprise Admins

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

I believe I am going crazy but maybe I am missing something.  I am trying to enumerate all members of Enterprise Admins.  When I look in DSA.MSC GUI tool, I see something like this with no nesting:

```
John
Bill
Jim
Sue
Mary
Spiderman
```

When I perform an LDP.EXE, PowerShell, or ADSIEDIT queries, I only see this:

```
John
Bill
Sue
Mary
```

Here are some of the methods I have tried to figure this delta out:

- Looked at Enterprise Admins in ADSIEDIT and view the member attribute.  Doesn't list Spiderman
- Looked at Enterprise Admins in LDP.EXE and view the member attribute.  Doesn't list Spiderman

Ran the following PowerShell queries

```
Get-ADgroup 'enterprise admins' -properties members | 
    select -Expandproperties members
# No Spiderman listed

Get-ADuser spiderman -properties memberof | 
    select -Expandproperties memberof
# No Enterprise Admins listed

Get-ADObject (Get-ADuser spiderman) -properties memberof | 
    select -Expandproperties memberof
# No Enterprise Admins listed

Get-AdObject (Get-ADgroup 'enterprise admins') -properties member | 
    select -Expandproperties members
# No Spiderman listed

Get-ADGroupMembers 'Enterprise Admins'
# **Spiderman listed!!!!!!**
```

**What am I missing here!  Why is spiderman listed in ADUC/Get-AdGroupMembers and no where else.  Am I going crazy?**

Comment: Why would you change the Primary Group? "The user's primary group applies only to users who log on to the network through Services for Macintosh or to who run POSIX-compliant applications. Unless you are using these services, there is no need to change the primary group from Domain Users, which is the default value."

Comment: Please see my comments below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within Windows the primaryGroupID indicates the account's primary group is used by the [posix subsystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_POSIX_subsystem).

Generally as [Bill_Stewart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2102693/bill-stewart) said, there is never a reason to change the primaryGroupID attribute. (Since Windows Server 2003)

The primaryGroupID attribute:
[The user is a member of its primary group, although the group is not listed in the user's memberOf attribute. Likewise, a group object's member attribute will not list the user objects whose primaryGroupID is set to the group.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc220723.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the article!  Time for a deep tech dive into that.   By no means am I advocating for switching Primary IDs around.  My current client has this set up and it has posed a speed bump in my admin admin review.  Part of who I am is wanting to know the deep technical whys of something.  Like the why does AD act this way in actually removing the group membership if the two attributes when they are completely separate.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

So apparently, if I toggle the primary group ID to Enterprise admins, it hides it from from traditional queries.  Once I toggle it back to Domain Users, I am able to pull the queries back.

I wonder why it does this.

Comment: The primary group is not part of the `memberOf` attribute for an object. Don't change the primary group unless you understand its purpose and have a very specific reason to change it.

Comment: Corrrect, I'm a contractor working for a third party environment.  The problem is that AD will remove the DN of Spiderman out the member attribute in the EA group and remove the DN of EA from Spiderman's memberof attribute.  The traditional places to look for group membership is not an option at this point. My further question is why would this happen.  Why doesn't AD keep the DNs written in there when you change your Primary Group since those are two different attributes.

Comment: You can ask this specific question on serverfault. Stackoverflow is for programming questions.